# What does the unassigned static variable in PHP contain and why it prints blank space in a browser output window?

Tags: php, variables, static, default-value, static-variables

I've a following code snippet, please have a close look over it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <?php
    function myTest() {
      static $x;
      echo $x;
      $x++;
    }

    myTest();
    echo "<br>";
    myTest();
    echo "<br>";
    myTest();
   ?> 

  </body>
</html>
```

**Note :** The name of a file that contains above code is **demo.php** and its location on my laptop is **C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\demo.php**

The output I received when I run the above program into my browser by hitting the URL `http://localhost/php_playground/demo.php` is as below :

```
1
2
```

The screenshot of the same is also attached, please have a look at it.
[image: Output in a Browser Window]

1. My question is why the first line in the output is blank containing
   white space only?
2. Why it's not printing 0 or something like the word "NULL" or "Empty" something like that?
3. What does actually an unassigned static variable in PHP contain?
4. Does the default value of an static unassigned variable and the default value of unassigned normal variable differ?

Please give me the suitable answer with proper explanation.

Comment: `static $x;` will set the variable to `null` until you have explicitly set it to some other value. Since you're using it as an integer, give it a default value: `static $x = 0;` The "empty space" isn't the value, it's your `<br />`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : If so, then why it's not getting printed the word "null" into the browser output window?

Comment: Because `null` isn't a string. A variable is null when it is defined but has no value (and there for it doesn't print anything out). [Read more about NULL in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : As per my knowledge a string is a group of characters and the word "null" is a group formed by combining the characters(i.e. letters) 'n', 'u', 'l' and 'l'. Then why the string "null" is not getting printed in the browser output window?

Comment: `null` is a _data type_ not a string. It's `null` not `'null'`. Either that last comment was pure trolling, or you _really_ need to read the link I posted before going any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unassigned variable in PHP is cast to `NULL`.

`<?php echo NULL; ?>` doesn't echo anything, since `NULL` has no value.

From the [`NULL` page of the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) (Emphasis mine) :

> **The special NULL value represents a variable with no value**. NULL is the only possible value of type null.
>
> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - **it has not been set to any value yet.**
> - it has been unset().

Try replacing `echo $x;` with `var_dump($x)` in your snippet, it will output the following :

```
NULL
int(1)
int(2)
```

[Try it](https://eval.in/838719)

Answer (score 0):

Because NULL isn't anything, it's just a variable. You get 2 outputs because the first time you call it it get initialised with the value: 1 and then incrementing.

```
<?php
    function myTest() {
      static $x;
      echo $x;
      $x++;
    }

    myTest(); // INIT
    echo "<br>";
    myTest(); // 1
    echo "<br>";
    myTest(); // +1
   ?>
```

If you would declare $x as 0 then it would print 0.

Static variable ([classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)), ([functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static))

Comment: This is a bit confusing: _"Because is not NULL it's not anything"_. I guess you ment to say: _"Because NULL isn't anything"_?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson We all make mistakes... if you know what I mean, then someone else will too.

Answer (score 0):

Because in first step variable has assign in "static" but not contain any value;

it is the same that

```
$t = null;
echo $t;
```

> Why it's not printing 0 or something like the word "NULL" or "Empty" something like that?

Because null it is "nothing to see", variable defined but not have any value

> What does actually an unassigned static variable in PHP contain?
>   After you write this code

```
static $x;
```

You get range in global memory for save data into it.
We know that this variable linked with current space in memory.

After you write

```
unset($x)
```

You clear this space in memory(data) and delete link to this space(variable).

> Does the default value of an static unassigned variable and the default value of unassigned normal variable differ?

Yes it is different. Because if you don't assign variable

```
echo $test;
```

> you get error - **Notice**:  Undefined variable:

Because you really haven't this variable and after

```
static $test;
echo $test;
```

Now you have this variable and you have link to memory, but in this memory you don't have any data.